# A HUGE GAP in time: Complete problem for $\mathrm{strict}$-$\mathrm{SUBEXP}$

Tags: time-complexity

Normally, $\mathrm{SUBEXP}$ is defined to be the intersection of all $\mathrm{DTIME}(2^{n^\epsilon})$. That means each problem in this class has infinitely many exponential time algorithms with the exponent arbitrarily polynomially ($n^\epsilon$) small.

We all know that another closely related definition is also lurking around. Denote this stricter notion by $\mathrm{strict}$-$\mathrm{SUBEXP}$, we mean the class of computational decision problems such that  for each one of them, there exists ONE algorithm that runs in time less than $2^{n^\epsilon}$ for every $\epsilon$.

Is there any m-complete problem for $\mathrm{strict}$-$\mathrm{SUBEXP}$?

---

m-completeness: being complete by a Karp polynomial-time reduction

Comment: Complete under what type of reduction, polynomial time?

Comment: What does "m-complete" mean?