# $\mathrm{strict}$-$\mathrm{SUBEXP} \subset \mathrm{P}/\mathrm{poly} \implies \mathrm{strict}$-$\mathrm{SUBEXP} \subset \mathrm{MA}$

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Is anyone able to give a concise proof for the implication stated in the title? This is gonna be in stark contrast to this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96956/does-mathrmsubexp-subset-mathrmp-mathrmpoly-imply-anything).

---

For definition of $\mathrm{strict}$-$\mathrm{SUBEXP}$, see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96921/a-huge-gap-in-time-complete-problem-for-mathrmstrict-mathrmsubexp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can.

First of all, $\mathrm{poly}(\mathrm{subexp}) = \mathrm{subexp}$. So, we can simulate a *subexp* TM in *subexp* time. (This is in stark contrast to standard $\mathrm{SUBEXP}$ where we do not have any particular *subexp* machine)

Using this, we are able to put $\mathrm{strict}$-$\mathrm{SUBEXP}$ inside $\mathrm{PSPACE}$. The *poly space* TM would try every possible *poly-size circuit* and for each circuit make $2^n \times 2^n$ *local checking* of the tableaux using the current circuit. Note that the subexp TM never touches the $2^n$th cell and would cease to run long before $2^n$ time but that does not affect the poly space bound.

After putting $\mathrm{strict}$-$\mathrm{SUBEXP}$ inside $\mathrm{PSPACE}$, we use the result of interactive proving protocol with the power of the prover at most $\mathrm{P}^\mathrm{L}$ (where $\mathrm{L}$ is the language at hand) to push it down to $\mathrm{MA}$.